# What's the proper way to return a promise in this triggered Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I understand that for a triggered function, I must always return a promise. Look at the following example:

```js
//Example
exports.onAuthUserDelete = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
    let userId = user.uid;

    try {
        await firestore.collection('Users').doc(userId).delete();
        return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
```

My questions are:

1. Is `return Promise.resolve()` required or can I just do `return firestore.collection('Users').doc(userId).delete()`? If I opt to go with the latter, what would happen if the command failed? Will it still trigger `catch()`?
2. Is it better to just start every function with the following template to make sure a promise is always returned?

```js
//Is it better to start with this boilerplate
exports.onAuthUserDelete = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //My code goes here...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore's `delete` operation already returns a promise, so there's no need to create your own. As far as I can see that first example is example the same as:

```
exports.onAuthUserDelete = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
    return firestore.collection('Users').doc(user.uid).delete();
});
```

Given that, I highly recommend using the above shorter version.

Comment: My only problem is that, as I referenced in my example, the `userId` can be undefined. Thus, I was trying to do a condition check before actually executing the function.

Comment: The code you gave wasn't doing a check, so I also didn't include anything like that in my answer. But even with a `if (user != null)` you won't need to to create a custom promise. If there no asynchronous operation to perform, you can just return a value (any value really) right away.

Comment: @user3622260 Did you get any further with this?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response.I understand that the code would work, but I don't think I have the answers to my questions. Specifically, if I would need to do some checking & manipulation before (like my example, simplified), I wonder if `return Promise.resolve()` is correct. That leads to my second question if it is still programmatically correct to wrap every function inside a `return new Promise()` wrapper. I understand it's not required, but I need to know if it is ok to do so so I can make my own coding standard.